# IPC python unix-socket unavailable on windows

Tags: windows, ipc

I want to use the IPC interface between Python and geth. I use windows. But it seems that the unix-socket which IPC makes use of is not available in the windows version Python, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, UNIX sockets are a means of processes communicating with each other on *nix systems. The IPC on *nix is different from the one on windows.

A solution would be to create a virtual environment (virtual machine running a Linux flavor in an application such as Sun's [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) or [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/)) and run geth there.

Answer (score 0):

Since  Insider Build 17063, it's possible to use Unix sockets.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/12/19/af_unix-comes-to-windows/